# limiting number of email per hour joomla

Tags: php, email, joomla, smtp

I have a Joomla set up to use an external SMTP to send mails. The SMTP server is not under my control and no changes can be made to it.

Now I am seeing a lot of failed mails for account activation as well from user's complaint they do not receive any email. From the response of the admin of the SMTP server it is due to too many broadcast email. Example:

```
<xxx@gmail.com>: delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name  
not found. Name service error for name=gmail.com type=A: Host not found,
try again

<xxx@sangeetha.yahoo.com>: connect to
yahoo-wildcard.a05.yahoodns.net[98.137.132.14]: Operation timed out
```

My Joomla is connecting directly to the SMTP server so now I need a method to limit the number of emails sent each time to not flood the recipient server (Google, Yahoo, etc).

I've been scouring the net with less than clear answer and since this is a production website, a quick answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common problem with email marketing "on server", which is why I generally recommend to use off-site email platforms such as mailchimp or constantcontact instead. There are a range of Joomla modules that handle the integration for you.

Alternatively, you could look at Joomla components that handle mass email, most of these support "batching" of emails as well, however then the research work is on hour end of how much specific ISPs will let through.

The rate will also be affected by other factors, for example the actual content of your email and how spam compatible it is, if you are using a real name as a sender, if the email address you are sending of exists, SPF record, basically everything that affects a spam rating.

In summary, this is why I recommend to hand it off-site, some platforms even do a certain amount of emails for free.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood something. This is not mass email or newsletter. This is user registration and email will be sent for activation. Apparently users registered very fast and the large amount of email being sent is just too much to be received by the respective email server (eg: Gmail, Yahoo).